# Exception class code not working

Tags: python, class, exception, error-handling, subclass

This is what I got:

```
class E2Exception(Exception):
    pass


class E2OddException(E2Exception):
    pass


def raiser(x):
    if x == "So sue me!":
        raise E2Exception
    elif x != "So sue me!" and x not int:
        raise ValueError
    elif int(x) % 2 != 0:
        raise E2OddException()
    else:
        return None
```

How do we say if x is not convertible to an int, do this?

Also, I'm getting this error:

builtins.TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException

What does this mean?

Instructions below

---

`E2Exception`: an exception class that is a subclass of `Exception`.

`E2OddException`: an exception class that is a subclass of `E2Exception`.

`raiser`, a function that takes one parameter `x`, with the following behaviour:

- If `x == 'So sue me!'`, then `raiser(x)` raises `E2Exception` with the exception
  message `"New Yorker"`.
- If `x != 'So sue me!'`, but `x` is still not convertible 
  to an int (by calling `int(x)`), then `raiser(x)` raises a `ValueError`, without any 
  requirement on the exception message
- If `x` converts to an odd `int`, `raiser(x)` raises an 
  `E2OddException`, without any requirement on the exception message.
- Otherwise, `raiser(x)` does nothing (no return, no print, nothing at all).

Comment: You should `raise` the exceptions, not `return` them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do we say if x is not convertible to an int, do this?

```
try:
    int(x)
except ValueError:
    ... # Not convertable
else:
    ... # Convertable
```

In this case you might want to set a variable:

```
try:
    int(x)
except ValueError:
    intable = True
else:
    intable = False
```

which you can use inside the rest of your code (`elif x != "So sue me!" and not intable:` instead of `elif x != "So sue me!" and x not int:`).

---

Note that your

```
else:
    return None
```

is a no-op and can be removed entirely.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Question though, where would I embed the try--except--else code? Thanks again :)

Comment: Also, if x is not intable, does it automatically raise a ValueError? Would if x == ValueError: do this ...work?

Comment: You'd put this in your `raiser` function before you need to use the `intable` variable. // `int` raises a `ValueError` if it can't convert it's value, yes. I'm not sure how you expect `x` to ever *equal* `ValueError`, though.

Answer (score 1):

`int()` raises an exception when passed invalid input, so you can just let that happen and get rid of your `return ValueError` (which should really be a `raise`).

Also, Python automatically returns `None` if you don't explicitly return anything, so you can simplify your code to just:

```
def raiser(x):
    if x == "So sue me!":
        raise E2Exception("New Yorker")
    elif int(x) % 2 != 0:
        raise E2OddException()
```

Comment: If x == 'So sue me!', then raiser(x) raises E2Exception with the exception message "New Yorker". So, shouldn't it be raise E2Exception? How can I add the exception message to E2Exception? Much thanks

Comment: @muros: You can add a message to any exception just by passing it in as an argument: `raise E2Exception("New Yorker")`